# Make a specific DIV as index's landing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to design a **html5/css3** website like image blow that has *9 DIVs* , I want to make the **DIV #5** as my **landing index** page , therefore when a visitor opens my site he lands on DIV #5 and can surf my website using arrows in any direction.

How can I make this **DIV** as my landing index page with no URL editing or **htaccess** ! just **HTML5/CSS3** and **JS** !

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This quick **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JCCB3/3/)** should get you on the right path.

I used css to position the 5th div at the center of the screen, you can then use JS to navigate on the image changing `top` and `left` values.

HTML:

```
<img src="http://axgig.com/images/10610429937244008294.png"/>
```

CSS:

```
img{
    width:300%;
    height:300%;
    position:absolute;
    top:-100%;
    left:-100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chadocat , but how can I access to div 1-2-3 and 4 ? they're hidden on the fiddle !

Comment: Yesssss , I Got it Chadocat ! Very helpful Fiddle , Thank you so much